# Passing the values of variable values in C

Tags: c

I have a function say `formula(f)`, where f is a TERM and TERM is a structure pointer. This function prints a formula like `forall([U,V],implies(U,V)]`.These U and V are variable. I need to pass the values in these variable and have to generate the forumula according the combination of the values of the variable.Suppose the values of the U and V are 2 and 2 then it has to generate the 4 formulas like `forall([a_1,b_1]implies(a_1,b_1),forall([a_1,b_2]implies(a_1,b_2))` and so on... Can anybody please help me how to generate it?

Comment: Your question is _very_ unclear. What do you mean by `TERM`? Are U and V always integers? Do you need to generate the formulas for the Cartesian products of the sets of numbers from 1 to U and 1 to V? (ie: U=3 and V=4 means you have to generate for [1,1]..[1,4],[2,1]..[2,4]....[3,4]) Are you returning an array of C strings? How does `TERM` and the structure pointer relate to generating the formula and U and V?

Comment: I have some modules and i am using those modules to generate the formulas. According to the modoules, these are standard symbol variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that your `TERM` structure has U and V as integer members:

```
void formula(TERM* term) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  for (x; x < (*term).U; ++x)
    for (y; y < (*term).J; ++y)
      printf("forall([a_%d,b_%d] implies(a_%d, b_%d))\n", x, y, x, y);
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?